# NPM Run Build Error for React

Tags: html, reactjs, npm

I have an issue with an NPM Build Error in ReactJS. I checked the index.html file in the build folder and this is what it has. I have uploaded my build folder to AWS S3 for a static site but I have this issue. Is my index.html file supposed to have this code or am I supposed to have something else?

```
Html Webpack Plugin:
```

```
Error: Parse Error: <src="components/app.js" />
    <body>
      <div id="root"></div>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="/static/js/main.83185361.js">
     </script>
   </body>
    </html>
  - htmlparser.js:235 new HTMLParser
    [reactProject]/[html-minifier]/src/htmlparser.js:235:13

  - htmlminifier.js:944 minify
    [reactProject]/[html-minifier]/src/htmlminifier.js:944:3

  - htmlminifier.js:1297 exports.minify
    [reactProject]/[html-minifier]/src/htmlminifier.js:1297:10

  - index.js:296
    [reactProject]/[html-webpack-plugin]/index.js:296:16

  - util.js:16 tryCatcher
    [reactProject]/[bluebird]/js/release/util.js:16:23

  - promise.js:512 Promise._settlePromiseFromHandler
    [reactProject]/[bluebird]/js/release/promise.js:512:31

  - promise.js:569 Promise._settlePromise
    [reactProject]/[bluebird]/js/release/promise.js:569:18

  - promise.js:614 Promise._settlePromise0
    [reactProject]/[bluebird]/js/release/promise.js:614:10

  - promise.js:693 Promise._settlePromises
    [reactProject]/[bluebird]/js/release/promise.js:693:18

  - async.js:133 Async._drainQueue
    [reactProject]/[bluebird]/js/release/async.js:133:16

  - async.js:143 Async._drainQueues
    [reactProject]/[bluebird]/js/release/async.js:143:10

  - async.js:17 Immediate.Async.drainQueues
    [reactProject]/[bluebird]/js/release/async.js:17:14
</pre>
```

Package.json file

`"version": "0.1.0",  
 "private": true,  
  "proxy": {
    "/auth/facebook": {
      "target": "http://localhost:5000"
    },
    "/api/*": {
      "target": "http://localhost:5000"
    }   },   "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.18.0",
    "express": "^4.16.3",
    "imgix.js": "^3.3.2",
    "informed": "^1.7.4",
    "init": "^0.1.2",
    "lodash": "^4.17.10",
    "namor": "^1.0.1",
    "nodejs": "0.0.0",
    "react": "^16.2.0",
    "react-ga": "^2.5.3",
    "react-redux": "^5.0.7",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.2.2",
    "react-scripts": "^1.0.17",
    "react-table": "^6.8.0",
    "react-validation": "^3.0.7",
    "redux": "^4.0.0",
    "redux-form": "^7.4.2",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
    "semantic-ui": "^2.2.13",
    "slick-carousel": "^1.8.1"   },   "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": " react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "webpack": "webpack --mode production"   },   "devDependencies": {
    "prettier": "1.13.4",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.1.0"    }`

Comment: Nope the html file shoudn't have this in it. I'd try to reduce your project down into the smallest possible subset of code and then post more of it here.  Your webpack.config etc

Comment: @ChrisCousins I deleted the code that outputted in the index.html file then ran ```npm run build```& the exact code appeared again. Also, I don't have much room to delete files for the project since it's for work. If I upload my package.json file, will that help out any if you take a look at it?

Comment: sure ok package.json might help a little.

Comment: @ChrisCousins Package.json file is uploaded. It's beneath the index.html file above.

Comment: hmm given the parse error is in app.js it may be worth linking to the project somehow (or reducing down your project so it is so small you could put all the files in the question).

Comment: @ChrisCousins Thank you a lot for your advice Chris. I found the error. In my index.html file, I was missing "<script/>"